Angular MatPaginator navigation button are disabled
I have a mat-table with data received via an API http call. All the data is correctly received, but I can't navigate to the next page as all the buttons are disabled. Can you help me to fix the probleme and tu be able to navigate with next button?
ts:
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'label', 'price', 'action'];
  dataSource! : MatTableDataSource<Product>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  totalElements = 0;
  pageSize= 5;
  constructor(private productService: ProductService, private notificationService: NotificationService, private dialog: MatDialog) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadProducts(0, this.pageSize);
    }

  private loadProducts(number: number, pageSize: number) {
    this.productService.getAll(number, pageSize).subscribe({
      next: (responseProduct: ResponseProduct) => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Product>(responseProduct.products);
        this.totalElements = responseProduct.totalPage;
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      },
      error: () => console.log('error')
    })
  }

html:
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="label">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Label </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.label}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Prix </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.price}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <button mat-button (click)="openEditDialog(element)">Modifier</button>
        <button mat-button (click)="delete(element.id)">Supprimer</button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>


    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator  [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
                 [length]="totalElements"
                 [pageSize]="pageSize"
                 (page)="onPageChange($event)"
                 showFirstLastButtons
                 aria-label="Select page of periodic elements">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>

and the result is : enter image description here

The problem was fixed after changing totalElement from totalPage:3 to totalElement:12 …

Remove the "length" in the .html in your paginator. Material-angular take account about it when you use a MatTableDataSource. The property is used when we want to use a mat-paginator in others scenarios
